# Error al añadir producto en el carrito de compra PHP/MYSQLI

Tags: php, mysql, array, mysqli

Estoy realizando un sistema ecommerce nativamente con PHP, todo funciona perfectamente.

Excepto que no logro duplicar los productos en el carro de la compra cuando un cliente agrega el mismo producto pero con un color o talla diferente al que se haya agregado al carrito.

Si el cliente vuelve a elegir el mismo producto con una talla o color diferente lo que hace es actualizar la talla anterior y su color y esto no es lo ideal, lo ideal es que duplique ese producto.

**Ejemplo:** ***(Lo que deseo lograr cuando se agrega el mismo producto pero con talla o color diferente)***
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Mi código

**cart.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
require "config.ini.php";

$itemCount = isset($_SESSION['cart']) ? count($_SESSION['cart']) : 0;
if (isset($_SESSION['qty'])) {
    $meQty = 0;
    foreach ($_SESSION['qty'] as $meItem){
        $meQty = $meQty + $meItem;
    }
} else {
    $meQty = 0;
}

if (isset($_SESSION['cart']) and $itemCount > 0){
    $itemIds = "";
  foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $itemId){
    $itemIds = $itemIds . $itemId . ",";
  }

  $inputItems = rtrim($itemIds, ",");
  $meSql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE id in ({$inputItems})";
  $meQuery = mysqli_query($kcon, $meSql);
  $meCount = mysqli_num_rows($meQuery);
} else {
    $meCount = 0;
}

if ($meCount == 0){
    echo "<div class=\"alert alert-warning\">No hay artículos en la cesta</div>";
}else{
?>


<form action="updatecart.php" method="post" name="fromupdate">            
  <table class="table">
    <tr>
      <td>Producto</td>
      <td>Precio</td>
      <td>Cantidad</td>
      <td>Total</td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    $total_price = 0;
    $num = 0;
    $iva = 12;
    $shipping = 50;
    while ($meResult = mysqli_fetch_assoc($meQuery)){
        $key = array_search($meResult['id'], $_SESSION['cart']);
      $total_price = $total_price + ($meResult['price'] * $_SESSION['qty'][$key]);
      $intemId=$meResult['id'];
      $color = $_SESSION['colors'][$intemId];
      $size = $_SESSION['size'][$intemId];
      if ($total_price > 50){
        $shipping = 0;
      }
    ?>
    <tr>
      <td class="cart-image">
        <img src="<?php echo $meResult['image']; ?>" />
        <div class="cart-items">
          <h3><?php echo $meResult['product']; ?><?php echo $color; ?><?php echo $size?></h3>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="cart-price"><?php echo $meResult['price']; ?></td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="qtyupdate[<?php echo $num; ?>]" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['qty'][$key]; ?>" class="form-control" style="width: 60px;text-align: center;" autocomplete="off" data-validation="number" data-validation-allowing="float">
        <input type="hidden" name="arr_key_<?php echo $num; ?>" value="<?php echo $key; ?>">
        <a class="btn btn-danger btn-lg" href="removecart.php?itemId=<?php echo $meResult['id']; ?>" role="button">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>Eliminar</a>
      </td>
      <td>$<?php echo number_format(($meResult['price'] * $_SESSION['qty'][$key]),2); ?></td>
      <?php
        $num++;
    }
  }
?>
```

**updatecart.php**

```
<?php
session_start();

$itemId = isset($_GET['itemId']) ? $_GET['itemId'] : "";

$_SESSION['colors'][$itemId]=$_POST['colors'];
$_SESSION['size'][$itemId]=$_POST['size'];

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' and isset($_POST['qtyupdate'])) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['qtyupdate']); $i++) {
        $key = $_POST['arr_key_' . $i];
        $_SESSION['qty'][$key] = $_POST['qtyupdate'][$i];
    }

} else {
    $qty = isset($_POST['qty']) ? $_POST['qty'] : 1;
    if (!isset($_SESSION['cart'])) {
        $_SESSION['cart'] = array();
        $_SESSION['qty'][] = array();
    }
    if (in_array($itemId, $_SESSION['cart'])) {
        $key = array_search($itemId, $_SESSION['cart']);
        $_SESSION['qty'][$key] = $_SESSION['qty'][$key] + $qty;
    } else {
        array_push($_SESSION['cart'], $itemId);
        $key = array_search($itemId, $_SESSION['cart']);
        $_SESSION['qty'][$key] = $qty;
    }
}
header('location:cart.php');
?>
```

En el detalle del producto tengo el `select` donde se agrega la talla del producto:

```
<select name="size">
   <option value="XL">XL</option>
   <option value="M">M</option> 
</select>
```

Y el color del producto:

```
<div id="cont-colors">            
  <input id="id-7" type="radio" name="colors" class="selector-colors" value="Verde">
  <label for="id-7" title="Verde" id="colors" style="background:#008000;"></label>
  <input id="id-8" type="radio" name="colors" class="selector-colors" value="Azulado">
  <label for="id-8" title="Azulado" id="colors" style="background:#008080;"></label>
</div>
```

Y enviado:

```
 <form method="post" action="updatecart.php?itemId=3">
```

Comment: Según lo que dice el warning, `$itemId` es un array y no un string, puedes hacer un `print_r()` o un `var_dump()` en esa variable?

Comment: Tu foreach debería ser algo como `foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $item) ...` y esa línea: `$itemIds = $itemIds . $item['itemId'] . ",";`. De hecho `$itemIds` debería ser un array de los Ids y al final hacer un `implode()`.

Comment: Creo que la solución seria guardar el pedido en base de datos en lugar de en una variable de sesión. saludos!

Comment: No me parece una buena idea, esto implica estar pendiente de los registros en la base de datos, más eso los intentos de compras falsas y entre otros factores...

Comment: apoyo a @InfaktVeintiuno, en realidad eso es lo que hacen los sistemas actuales, guardar la información en un servidor del carrito (por eso es que puedes salir apagar tu compu irte a tu celular y ver el carrito y ahí están los productos).

Comment: @RandallSandoval Eso se puede hacer con la cookies sin necesidad de registrar a la base de datos los productos añadidos al carrito de compra, hacer eso implica muchos registros falsos y mucha dependencia de la base de datos cunado un sitio llegue tener gran cantidad de público...

Comment: @RandallSandoval para ver más tarde un producto esta implementado el favorito, el único registro valido que se debe registrar es cuando el cliente completa la compra...

Comment: @J.Doe entonces con las cookies puedes hacer que desde la computadora y desde el celular puedas ver el mismo carrito?? o si empiezas una compra en tu casa y después la continúas en tu trabajo en una computadora diferente puedas ver los mismo productos en el carrito??

Comment: @J.Doe Si quieres hacer las pruebas, te invito a que abras Amazon, hagas el login, agregues algo al carrito, salgas del navegador, borres todos los datos del navegado (incluyendo cookies), le vuelvas a dar al login y me cuentas si te aparecen o no lo que habías agregado al carrito.

Comment: @RandallSandoval Pueda que tenga la razón pero existen muchos sistemas diferentes como el de Godaddy añado producto al carrito ingreso en otra parte los productos añadidos no se muestran en otro computador/lapto o teléfono/celular, el sistema solo esta reflejado a compras 100% fiables no para futuras decisiones, lo siento pero eso no es lo que estoy buscando... Todo debe ser por sessiones

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Según veo el código la razón por la que se modifica  la cantidad y el color es por que en `updatecart.php` estas sobre escribiendo su valor.

```
$_SESSION['colors'][$itemId]=$_POST['colors'];
$_SESSION['size'][$itemId]=$_POST['size'];
```

**Como los mismos artículos tienen el mismo id aun que tengan el distinto color o tamaño el ultimo color y tamaño que se asigne sera el valor general del articulo.**

Para solucionar este problema debes crear mas dimensiones a tu matriz una por Articulo,Color, y Tamaño:

```
$_SESSION['car'][$idArticulo][$color][$size] = $cantidad;
//$_SESSION['car'][1]['verde']['M'] = 2
```

Esto necesitara cambiar la lógica de la aplicación específicamente como guardas el carrito de compra.

Podrías hacelo así:

**cart.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
require "config.ini.php";


/**
 * Un elemento del carrito llegaria de la siguente forma:
 *
 * $_SESSION['car'][$idArticulo][$color][$size] = $cantidad;
 * $_SESSION['car'][1][verde][M] = 2
 *
 *
 */



/** Guardamos los el arreglo de articulos en una variable
 * para hacerla mas legible
 */

$articulos = isset ($_SESSION['cart'])  ?
             $_SESSION['cart'] :
             array();



/* Obtenemo el numero de articulos solicitados */
$itemCount = count($articulos);

/**
 * Inicalizamos variables  que se usaran en el while.
 * (Cambio de posicion para hacer mas legible el codigo )
 */

$total_price = 0;
$num = 0;
$iva = 12;
$shipping = 50;


/**
 * Cantidad de articulos totales en el carrito
 * (No utilizado en el codigo original)
 */

$meQty = 0;

/**
 * Obtenemos los ids de los articulos y los convertimos
 * en cadena seperada por comas
 */

$inputItems = implode(',',array_keys($_SESSION['car']));

/* Ejecutamos el query */
$meSql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE id in ($inputItems)";
$meQuery = mysqli_query($kcon, $meSql);

/* Numero de articulos que existen en la base de datos */
$meCount = mysqli_num_rows($meQuery);

/* Si no hay articulos en el carrito */
if ($meCount == 0) :

?>
  <div class="alert alert-warning">No hay artículos en la cesta</div>

<?php

  /* Si no hay articulos detenemos la ejecucion */
  exit(0);

endif;

/* Continuamos si hay articulos en el carrito */





?>
<form action="updatecart.php" method="post" name="fromupdate">
  <table class="table">
    <tr>
      <td>Producto</td>
      <td>Precio</td>
      <td>Cantidad</td>
      <td>Total</td>
    </tr> <?php
    /* Inicia while */
    while ($meResult = mysqli_fetch_assoc($meQuery)):

      $id = $meResult['id'];
      foreach($articulos[$meResult['id']]  as $color => $sizes) :
        foreach($sizes as $size => $cantidad) :


          /**
           * Sumamos las cantidades para obtner la
           * cantidad total de articulos solicitados
           * (en codigo original no observo algun uso)
           * Supongo que se usa como sumatoria en la tabla
           * por ello lo agrego aqui.
          */

          $meQty += $cantidad;

          $precio = $meResult['price'] * $cantidad;

          $total += $precio;

        ?>
          <tr>
            <td class="cart-image">

              <img src="<?php echo $meResult['image']; ?>" />

              <div class="cart-items">
                <h3>
                    <?php echo $meResult['product']; ?>
                    <?php echo $color; ?>
                    <?php echo $size; ?>
                </h3>
              </div>

            </td>

            <td class="cart-price">

              <?php echo $meResult['price']; ?>

            </td>


            <td>

              <input type="text"
                     name="qtyupdate[<?php echo $id; ?>][<?php echo $color; ?>][<?php echo $size; ?>]"
                     value="<?php echo $cantidad ?>"
                     class="form-control"
                     style="width: 60px;text-align: center;"
                     autocomplete="off"
                     data-validation="number"
                     data-validation-allowing="float" >

              <input type="hidden"
                     name="arr_key_<?php echo $num; ?>"
                     value="<?php echo $key; ?>" >


              <a class="btn btn-danger btn-lg"
                 href="removecart.php?itemId=<?php echo $id; ?>"
                 role="button" >

                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>Eliminar

              </a>

            </td>

            <td>

              $<?php echo number_format($precio, 2); ?>

            </td>

          </tr><?php

        endforeach;
      endforeach;
    endwhile;


?>

    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" class="cart-image">&nbsp;</td>

      <!-- Numero total de Articulos -->
      <td><?php echo $meQty ?></td>

      <!-- Cantidad total a pagar -->
      <td>$<?php echo number_format($total, 2); ?></td>

    </tr>
  </table class="table">
</form>
```

**updatecart.php**

```
<?php

session_start();

if (
    $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' &&
    isset($_POST['qtyupdate']) ) {

  $cantidades = isset($_POST['qtyupdate']) ?
              $_POST['qtyupdate'] :
              array();

  foreach ($cantidades as $idArticulo => $colores) {


      foreach($colores as $color => $sizes) {

        foreach($sizes as $size => $cantidad) {

          $_SESSION['cart'][$idArticulo][$color][$size] = $cantidad;
        }
      }
  }

  header('Location: cart.php');
  exit(0);
}



/* Cuando deseas modificar un solo elemento */

$itemId = isset($_GET['itemId']) ? $_GET['itemId'] : "";
$qty = isset($_POST['qty']) ? $_POST['qty'] : 1;

/*
*
* Si el color o el tamaño cambian deberas enviar el color y
* tamaño anterior para localizarlos en el carrito
*
**/

/*
*  valores anteriores necesarios para localizar el articulo
*  en la matriz
**/

$colorAnt = isset($_POST['colorsAnt']) ?
            $_POST['colorsAnt'] :
            '';
$sizeAnt  = isset($_POST['sizeAnt']) ?
            $_POST['sizeAnt'] :
            '';


/*
*  Si los nuevos valores no estan definidos consideramos
*  que no cambiaron y son iguales a los anteriores
*
**/

$size     = isset($_POST['size']) ?
            $_POST['size'] :
            $sizeAnt;

$color    = isset($_POST['colors']) ?
            $_POST['colors'] :
            $colorAnt;
/*
*  El valor anterior de la cantidad se asignara despues
*  Primero hay que asegurarse que el articulo esta presente
*  en el matriz (Carro de compra)
**/
$qty = isset($_POST['qty']) ?
            $_POST['qty'] :
            1;

$error = '';





// Validacion de Parametros
if (empty($itemId) ||
    ( (empty($colorAnt) || empty($sizeAnt)) &&
      (empty($color) || empty($size))
    )
) {

  $error = urlencode(
    '¡ Parametros incompletos no es posible localizar o ' .
    'agregar el articulo!'
  );

  $error .= '?error=' . $error;

  header('Location: cart.php' .$error );
  header('Location: cart.php?error=' .$error );
  exit(0);


} // Termina validacion de parametros



/*
 * Agregar un articulo al carrito si no lo necesitas puedes
 * omitir la signacion
 */

//si no se envian los colores y tamaños anteriores
if (empty($colorAnt) || empty($sizeAnt)) {

    $error = '';
    //$error = '! El articulo no se encuentra en el carrito !';



    /*
     * Si se envian el color y tamaño nuevo se considera que
     * hay que agregar el articulo al carrito.
     * Si no deseas esta funcionalidad puedes comentar la
     * linea siguiente y descomentar error
     */

      $_SESSION['car'][$itemId][$color][$size] = $qty;

     header('Location: cart.php' .$error );
     header('Location: cart.php?error=' .$error );
     exit(0);


} //Aqui termina agregar nuevo articulo



/* validar la existencia del articulo en el carrito */
if (! isset($_SESSION['car'][$itemId])) {

    /*
     * El articulo no existe en el carrito
     */
    $error = urlencode(
      '¡ El articulo no se encuentra en el carrito !'
    );


    $error .= '?error=' . $error;
    header('Location: cart.php' . $error );
    header('Location: cart.php?error=' . $error );
    exit(0);

}





/*
 * Si el usuario envio cero para cantidad se elimina el
 * articulo
*/
if (empty($qty)) {

  if (
       isset($_SESSION['car'][$itemId][$colorAnt]) &&
       isset($_SESSION['car'][$itemId][$colorAnt][$sizeAnt])
  ) {

    unset($_SESSION['car'][$itemId][$colorAnt][$sizeAnt]);
  }

  header('Location: cart.php' .$error );
  header('Location: cart.php?error=' .$error );
  exit(0);

} // Aqui termina eliminar articulo





/* Si cambio el tamaño*/
if ($size != $sizeAnt) {


  /* Si tambien cambio el color */
  if ($color != $colorAnt) {

    /* validamos que exista el elemento en el arreglo */
    if (
       isset($_SESSION['car'][$itemId][$colorAnt]) &&
       isset($_SESSION['car'][$itemId][$colorAnt][$sizeAnt])
    ) {


      /* Eliminamos el elemento de ese tamaño */
      unset($_SESSION['car'][$itemId][$colorAnt][$sizeAnt]);


      /* Si ya no hay articulos de ese color */
      if (count($_SESSION['car'][$itemId][$colorAnt]) == 0 ) {

        /* Eliminamos el articulo */
        unset($_SESSION['car'][$itemId][$colorAnt][$sizeAnt]);
      }


    }

    $_SESSION['car'][$itemId][$color][$size] = $qty;

  } else {
    /* Si cambio el tamaño pero no cambio el color */


    if (
     isset($_SESSION['car'][$itemId][$colorAnt]) &&
     isset($_SESSION['car'][$itemId][$colorAnt][$sizeAnt])
    ) {


      /* Eliminamos el elemento de ese tamaño */
      unset($_SESSION['car'][$itemId][$colorAnt][$sizeAnt]);


      $_SESSION['car'][$itemId][$colorAnt][$size] = $qty;


    }

  }

  header('Location: cart.php' .$error );
  header('Location: cart.php?error=' .$error );
  exit(0);
  exit(0);

}



/*
 * Si solo cambio el color. Para el caso de ambas cosas ya
 * lo considera si cambio el tamaño
*/

if (($size === $sizeAnt) && ($color != $colorAnt)){

  /* validamos que exista el elemento en el arreglo */
  if (
     isset($_SESSION['car'][$itemId][$colorAnt]) &&
     isset($_SESSION['car'][$itemId][$colorAnt])
  ) {


    /* Eliminamos el elemento de ese tamaño */
    unset($_SESSION['car'][$itemId][$colorAnt][$sizeAnt]);


    /* Si ya no hay articulos de ese color */
    if (count($_SESSION['car'][$itemId][$colorAnt]) == 0 ) {

      /* Eliminamos el articulo */
      unset($_SESSION['car'][$itemId][$colorAnt][$sizeAnt]);
    }


  }

  $_SESSION['car'][$itemId][$color][$sizeAnt] = $qty;
  header('Location: cart.php' .$error );
  header('Location: cart.php?error=' .$error );
  exit(0);
  exit(0);
}



/* Si no se cumple alguna de las condiciones anteriores */

$error = urlencode(
  '¡ Erro al modificar el carrito de compra !'
);


$error .= '?error=' . $error;

header('Location: cart.php' .$error );
header('Location: cart.php?error=' .$error );
exit(0);
```

Espero esto aclare mi punto.

Comment: Por que los 2 votos negativos a esta respuesta? deberían decir porque y no solo dar votos negativos...

Comment: es correcto. deberías reportarlo

Comment: Claro si me indicas como pasarte mi correo sin publicarlo

Answer (score 1):

Con el código que manejas Actualmente no hay manera de Duplicar un item en tus variables de sesión, la única manera de agregar este alcance en tu aplicación seria replantear la estructura a de como manejas los items, no digo que dejes de usar sesiones.

yo te recomendaría que por cada item generes un array con un indice adicional

```
$_SESSION['colors'][$itemId][$tempid]
```

y puedes asociar el boton a este $tempid y como seria el id pues puedes crear una estructura:

```
Id Real  Id Temporal
000001   000001-A # Asi o
000001   000001-1 # de esta manera
```

de esta manera si agregar un Item, puedes probar si existe un item con sus características:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['colors'][$itemId][$tempid]) && isset($_SESSION['size'][$itemId][$tempid])){
    #Nuevo Item
    #Generas el Codigo Temporal
    $c=true;
    $cc=1;
    While($c==true){
        if(isset($_SESSION['colors'][$itemId][$itemId.'-'.$cc])){# Verifica si el id Existe
            $cc++;
        }else{
            $tempid=$itemId.'-'.$cc;
            $c=false;
        }
    }
}
# esto indicara que cuando guardes; o se auto genera el nuevo Id temporal o actualiza uno existente
$_SESSION['colors'][$itemId][$tempid]=$_POST['colors'];
$_SESSION['size'][$itemId][$tempid]=$_POST['colors'];
```

**Deberás adaptar esta respuesta a tus necesidades, si la solución no aporta una respuesta a tu pregunta favor no botes negativo, simplemente ignórala..**

Comment: gracias lo probaré más tarde, yo no voto negativo son otras personas que votan negativo sin decir: motivo, circunstancia o porque etc...

Comment: @FranciscoNuñes existe un problema en el código proporcionado me muestra este mensaje de error ***Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in C:\xampp\htdocs\cart\updatecart.php on line 12***  la linea ´12´ selecciona el siguiente código ´if(isset($_SESSION['colors'][$itemId][$itemId.'-'.$cc]){# Verifica si el id Existe´

Comment: ok y no lo encontraste??, dice que es en la linea 12 ... no se cual sea la linea 12 en tu codigo.