# ¿Cómo duplicar una sesión?

Tags: php, array, mysqli, session

> Duplicar una sesión siempre en cuando los datos sea diferente pero con el mismo identificador (ID).

La estructura de la base de datos de **productos**:

```
id   product  price
1     shirt    30
2     pants    34
```

La estructura de la base de datos del **color** del producto:

```
id   product_id   color
 1      1         blue
 2      1        yellow
 3      2         White
 4      2         black
```

La estructura de la base de datos de la **talla** del producto:

```
id   product_id   size
 1      1          XS
 2      1          S
 3      2          M
 4      2         XL
```

Los datos (`color` y `size`) son enviados por el método `POST`

```
$_SESSION['colors'][$itemId]=$_POST['colors'];
$_SESSION['size'][$itemId]=$_POST['size'];
```

Y el `id` del producto por el método GET.

```
 $itemId = isset($_GET['itemId']) ? $_GET['itemId'] : "";
```

Necesito duplicar la sesión de un producto al elegir un color o tamaño diferente.

**Ejemplo**

```
-----------------------------------
 Product       Quantity     Price
-----------------------------------
 Shirt blue S      1          30
 Shirt blue XS     1          30
 Shirt yellow S    1          30
```

Si añadimos el mismo producto con el mismo valor (Shirt blue S), actualizar sólo la cantidad.

```
-----------------------------------
 Product       Quantity     Price
-----------------------------------
 Shirt blue S      2          60
```

No logro conseguir la duplicación del producto, Solo actualiza los mismos valores seleccionados.

código **updatecart.php**

```
<?php
session_start();

$itemId = isset($_GET['itemId']) ? $_GET['itemId'] : "";

//SESSION colors
$_SESSION['colors'][$itemId]=$_POST['colors'];
//SESSION size
$_SESSION['size'][$itemId]=$_POST['size'];

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' and isset($_POST['qtyupdate'])) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['qtyupdate']); $i++) {
        $key = $_POST['arr_key_' . $i];
        $_SESSION['qty'][$key] = $_POST['qtyupdate'][$i];
    }

} else {
    $qty = isset($_POST['qty']) ? $_POST['qty'] : 1;
    if (!isset($_SESSION['cart'])) {
        $_SESSION['cart'] = array();
        $_SESSION['qty'][] = array();
    }
    if (in_array($itemId, $_SESSION['cart'])) {
        $key = array_search($itemId, $_SESSION['cart']);
        $_SESSION['qty'][$key] = $_SESSION['qty'][$key] + $qty;
    } else {
        array_push($_SESSION['cart'], $itemId);
        $key = array_search($itemId, $_SESSION['cart']);
        $_SESSION['qty'][$key] = $qty;
    }
}
header('location:cart.php');
?>
```

Código **cart.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
$itemCount = isset($_SESSION['cart']) ? count($_SESSION['cart']) : 0;
if (isset($_SESSION['qty'])){
    $meQty = 0;
    foreach ($_SESSION['qty'] as $meItem){
        $meQty = $meQty + $meItem;
    }
}else{
    $meQty = 0;
}

if (isset($_SESSION['cart']) and $itemCount > 0){
    $itemIds = "";
    foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $itemId){
        $itemIds = $itemIds . $itemId . ",";
    }
    $inputItems = rtrim($itemIds, ",");
    $meSql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE id in ({$inputItems})";
    $meQuery = mysqli_query($kcon, $meSql);
    $meCount = mysqli_num_rows($meQuery);
}else{
    $meCount = 0;
}

if ($meCount == 0){
    echo "<div>No items in the basket</div>";
}else{
?>

    <form action="updatecart.php" method="post" name="fromupdate">            
    <table class="table">
    <tr>
    <td>Product</td>
    <td>Price</td>
    <td>Quantity</td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    $total_price = 0;
    $num = 0;
    while ($meResult = mysqli_fetch_assoc($meQuery)){
        $key = array_search($meResult['id'], $_SESSION['cart']);
        $total_price = $total_price + ($meResult['price'] * $_SESSION['qty'][$key]);
        $intemId=$meResult['id'];
        $color = $_SESSION['colors'][$intemId];
        $size = $_SESSION['size'][$intemId];
    }
    ?>
    <tr>
    <td class="cart-image">
    <h3><?php echo $meResult['product']; ?> <?php echo $color; ?> <?php echo $size?></h3>
    </td>
    <td class="cart-price"><?php echo $meResult['price']; ?></td>
    <?php
    $num++;
    }
    ?>                                    
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Ayuda por favor, duplicar la sesión de un producto al elegir un color o tamaño diferente.

Gracias.

Comment: El código parece correcto (aunque no se actualiza el precio). No acabo de ver el problema.

Comment: @MiquelColl No amigo funciona correctamente, lo que sucede es que necesito duplicar el producto. Por decir yo como cliente quiero comprar el mismo producto pero en diferentes colores o talla??? entonces lo ideal seria que al añadir el mismo producto al carrito de compras el producto se duplicara porque tiene valores distintos (color o talla).

Comment: @MiquelColl  El código funciona así si vuelves a seleccionar el mismo producto pero con un color rojo y si vuelves hacer lo mismo con otro color amarillo este te actualiza los valores. Es decir estaba rojo pero lo pasa a ser amarillo. Si yo quiero el mismo producto pero en dos colores diferentes no puedo? Tendría que comprar el mismo producto dos veces. No se si me explico bien amigo :)

Comment: @MiquelColl Amigo observa la tienda online [http://imyshop.tk/index.php](http://imyshop.tk/index.php) clic en el producto Camiseta manga corta seleccionas el producto color y talla y clic en comprar vuelves a seleccionar el mismo pero con otra talla y otro color observa que se actualiza los valores, lo ideal es duplicar el producto cuando se añado un valor diferente.

Answer (score -3):

**UPDATE luego de los comentarios de JDoe**:

```
$key = sprintf("%s_%s_%s", $itemId, $_POST['colors'], $_POST['size']);

if (!array_key_exists($key, $_SESSION['cart'])) {
  $_SESSION['cart'][$key] = array(
    'itemId' => $itemId,
    'color' => $_POST['colors'],
    'size' => $_POST['sizes'],
    'qyt'  => 1
  );
} else {
  // Si ya existia, depende de ti, si quieres aumentar en uno, dejar igual o quitar el producto
  // Asumo que quieres sumar uno
  $_SESSION['cart'][$key]['qty'] ++;
}
```

gracias a esto, cuando muestras el carro, solo recorrer el array `cart` de la session y así mantienes los distintos colores/tallas mejor ordenados en una variable y no N

---

Se me ocurre la siguiente solución:

en **updatecart.php**:

```
//SESSION colors
if( !array_key_exists($itemId, $_SESSION['colors']) ) $_SESSION['colors'][$itemId] = array();
if( !array_key_exists($itemId, $_SESSION['size']) ) $_SESSION['size'][$itemId] = array();

$_SESSION['colors'][$itemId][] = $_POST['colors'];
$_SESSION['colors'][$itemId] = array_unique($_SESSION['colors'][$itemId]);
//SESSION size
$_SESSION['size'][$itemId][] = $_POST['size'];
$_SESSION['size'][$itemId] = array_unique($_SESSION['size'][$itemId]);
```

Luego solo te quedaría modificar **`cart.php`** para que mostrase el carro de la forma correcta.

---

**Esto es una recomendación personal.**
Este código:

```
$itemIds = "";
foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $itemId){
    $itemIds = $itemIds . $itemId . ",";
}
$inputItems = rtrim($itemIds, ",");
```

lo encuentro un poco díficil de leer de buenas a primeras, para la tarea simple que hace, además de no utilizar las herramientas propias que te da el lenguaje. Cuando necesito hacer algo de este estilo aplico lo siguiente:

```
$inputItems = implode(', ', $_SESSION['cart']); // Aprovechamos que tus ids ya son un array
```

gracias a esto, queda más claro el código y te evitas un foreach.

Comment: amigo seguramente si funcionara bien este código solo duplicaría el color y la talla pero no el producto verdad? Lo ideal seria duplicar el producto al añadir el color o talla diferente ejemplo: id1 = camisa color -> rojo - talla L id1 = camisa color -> negro - talla L

Comment: Duplicar la sessión también implica el producto mostrando dos registro o más según los colores o talla añadidos al mismo id del producto.

Comment: @J.Doe Ya comprendo mejor tu problemática. La solución planteada está basada en lo que tienes en tu código. Personalmente, en la sesion mantendría en `$_SESSION['cart']` un objeto/array/mapa que tenga toda la información y si se desea actualizar, buscaría dentro de este array `cart`; no mantendría arrays distintos (`colores`, `tallas`) ya que complica más que nada el código. No sé si me explico

Comment: Observa amigo [http://imyshop.tk/index.php](http://imyshop.tk/index.php) selecciona la talla y un color y comprar vuelve añadir el mismo producto con otro color y otra talla y comprar observaras que se actualiza los valores (color y talla). Entonces lo ideal es duplicar el mismo producto al tener un valor diferente. Por que caso contrario deberías comprar dos veces para poder comprar el mismo producto pero con un color o talla diferente.

Comment: @PabloAlcantar No estaría mal que esta pregunta la borraras y la pasaras a la pregunta del mismo tema enlazada  que es la siguiente https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/19655/error-al-añadir-producto-en-el-carrito-de-compra-php-mysqli saludos.